# Joining 2 Entity in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, entity, navigation-properties

Hibernate why don't use JOIN in sql query on navigation property. (I used spring-boot)

When I used following code two times SELECT query running. I expect it to do it in a single sql statement.

*List articles = articleRepository.findByUserId(userId);*

Hibernate: select a1_0.id,a1_0.creation_date,a1_0.text,a1_0.update_date,a1_0.user_id from articles a1_0 where a1_0.user_id=?

Hibernate: select u1_0.id,a1_0.user_id,a1_0.id,a1_0.creation_date,a1_0.text,a1_0.update_date,u1_0.creation_date,u1_0.is_active,u1_0.name,u1_0.surname,u1_0.update_date,u1_0.username from users u1_0 left join articles a1_0 on u1_0.id=a1_0.user_id where u1_0.id=?

---

When I use the code below a SELECT query is created, JOIN is used and it works fine.

*User user = userRepository.findById(userId).get();*

Hibernate: select u1_0.id,a1_0.user_id,a1_0.id,a1_0.creation_date,a1_0.text,a1_0.update_date,u1_0.creation_date,u1_0.is_active,u1_0.name,u1_0.surname,u1_0.update_date,u1_0.username from users u1_0 left join articles a1_0 on u1_0.id=a1_0.user_id where u1_0.id=?

**My Entities are "User" and "Article"**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
@Getter
@Setter
public class User extends BaseEntity {
    
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String username;
    private boolean isActive = Boolean.TRUE;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Article> articles;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ARTICLES")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Article extends BaseEntity {

    private String text;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

**My Repositories are "UserRepository" and "ArticleRepository"**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

```
@Repository
public interface ArticleRepository extends JpaRepository<Article, Integer> {
    
    List<Article> findByUserId(int id);
}
```

Creating a single SQL query using relationships between Hibernate Entities such as 1:M, M:1, 1:1

Comment: As mentioned in the duplicate, using `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` results in select-fetching in stead of join-fetching. You can enforce join-fetching by writing your own JPQL query and adding the `join fetch` keyword.